# Is there a fundamental reason why in the Standard Model, there is no Feynman rule for a vertex with more than 4 legs?

Tags: standard-model, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, dimensional-analysis, interactions

In Standard Model, there are vertices with 3 legs (example: $W l\nu$) and with 4 legs (example: $WWWW$).

Is there a fundamental reason why in the Standard Model, there is no Feynman rule where a vertex has more than 4 legs?

Is this possible in Beyond-the-Standard-Model theories?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fundamental?  [Power counting](https://rdmc.nottingham.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/internal/102/Quantum%20Field%20Theory/output12.pdf). The SM is ***renormalizable***, that is,  without dimensionful couplings. The lagrangian must have dimension 4, and any vertex with 5 legs or more would dictate a coupling of dimension -1 or less. So the gauge couplings *g,g'*, the Yukawa *y*, etc, are all dimensionless.

(You do have Feynman diagrams of higher dimension, like a 4-fermion diagram with exchange of a vector boson: four fermions are of dimension 6. So in the *effective* theory for that, it is summarized by  4-Fermi coupling with a dimensionful (-2)  effective $G_F$.)

Anything is possible in BSM theories, but, normally, one looks for [renormalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization#Renormalizability) theories as well—otherwise one simply tacks on unrenormalizable effective interactions to the SM, which afford little "explanation" of the energy behavior of the amplitudes.